# How to drill a 3/4" or larger hole in a steel bracket?

Tags: drill, metal, hole

I purchased a wheel set and the bracket has a hole drilled in the wrong place.  I need to make the hole larger.

Will a titanium bit (like the link below) drill thru a 1/8" or 3/16" steel bracket? If not, what do you sugggest to make the hole larger?

Drill bit: [http://www.amazon.com/Neiko%C2%AE-10194A-Shank-Titanium-Increments/dp/B000FZ2UOY/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1453485308&sr=8-1-fkmr0&keywords=TITANIUM+STEEL+METAL+UNIT+1%2F4%22-1-3%2F8%22](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FZ2UOY)

Bracket:  [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're referring to the hole at top center in your photo, you'd have a hard time drilling a new hole halfway overlapping an old hole. A better approach would be a rotary grinding tool. Any abrasive grinding bit will allow you to enlarge the hole enough to get the bolt through.

Be aware that this will tend to heat the part being worked. A damp rag on the part near the hole will absorb heat and prevent paint damage.

Alternatively, clamp a scrap bar over the original bar and drill through both. The scrap bar will act as a drill guide. You can use any high-speed steel bits available. There's no need for titanium or other exotic stuff.

Comment: I thought of just enlarging the existing hole but your idea of grinding an opening where I need it makes sense.  What type of rotary grinding tool would work on this steel bracket?

Comment: You mentioned drilling a hole overlapping the existing hole.  I had not thought of that.  If I started with a small diameter bit and then used a larger diameter bit, why would I have trouble?  It actually sounds like a good idea.  I have a set of bits that should work.

Comment: It'll tear out at some point and leave you with a mess. The only way you can re-drill is if you clamp another piece of material over the original to act as a drill guide.

Comment: That guide sounds like a great idea!